# My text classifier behaves like regex

Tags: text-classification, support-vector-machine

I'm trying to train binary classifier that classifies ask to ask programming questions, programming questions that say "I'm getting an error about x/I have problem about x" but don't say the error/problem and those who ask inadequate questions ask for help in dm. I looked models and linear svm did better job than others. So i trained linear svm. But when linear svm see certain word phrases like "Who knows" etc. it tends to give positive label. Because in dataset there is so much "Who knows javascript" like questions. So when i test "Who knows ewsamfsakfas" model gives 1 label. It behaves like regex.

So i tried to add new datas by my hand like that:

- "Who knows safasfasfsa" -> 0
- "Who knows msafmsafmsamf" -> 0
- "Who knows smafsamfsnafn" -> 0
- ...

Weirdly... SVM can't learn properly and still gives 1 label. I even tried adding more data it finally learned to give 0 label. But when i add new real world 1 label data and tested again "Who knows ansjafsanfjnas" it gived 1 label...

I don't have good math so i don't know what's going on. But i need good solution for that. Because it's practically regex... Am i need to train second classifier that classifies "it is programming question or not"? Or is there any other possible solution?

Comment: What features you use to describe the text? How you encode it and train the model? Have you tried TF-IDF as feature?

Comment: Yes i use tf-idf vectorizer i forgot to say that sorry. If unique words mean features then... you know there are many feature. example datas are "is there any java expert around", "pls help my unity problem in dm" etc.

Comment: Do you remove the stop words? If not you should, and you may add "who" and "knows" to them too. Probably the model is learning just a correlation with the count of such works, you want to avoid that

Comment: i lowercased and removed other than a-z. but didnt remove stop words. because in turkish stop words there are "is there", "who" etc. if i remove stop words then i thinked how can model undestand data is question or not?